# How to pass parameter as POST from BIRT Input parameter window

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I want to know how to pass report parameter as post request from birt input parameter winndow.Currentlyit showing reportname and output format in url(ie:pdf).How can i change this as post request.Where i need to make changes? Can anyone help on this

Comment: How are you conecting to your report?  (i.e. Apache Tomcat)

Comment: tw0 of the parameters are passing from php page as hidden variable and one of he parameter is receiving from birt input parameter window.After sumbit it generated in pdf format.Problem is in url it showing report name and file format.(ie:pdf).I dont want to see it in url.If everything is passing from php page,then report names are not showing in url.If one of the parameter is passing from birt input window,then it is not working.i am connecting through tomcat

Comment: Are you using the free version of BIRT or the commercial (purchased) version?

Comment: @James Jenkins..is any major difference?

Comment: I use the free version also, and can not address solutions with the paid version.  In the free version, I only now how to send via url, and thought that was the only option.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992465) it may give you some helpful hints

Answer (score 0):

`There are two alternatives came into my mind.`

```
`The first way is to use the jsp tag in the web page.and you can get param from the post and use the param.you can google the birt jsp tag.`
```

`And i infer that you don't want users know the parameters,so you can code the params and add the beforOpen function of the design file.In the beforOpen function you can decode the params. Those are my thoughts. And you can try it. :)`

Comment: Can you expand on the solution?  What are the required commponets? Can this be done with the "BIRT Viewer" available for free BIRT.