# BIRT reports - add parameter through script

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, birt

I have a BIRT report that uses a query like below.

`select 
    Dealer,
    Name
from customerA where id = ?
    union all
select 
    Code as Dealer,
    last_name as Name
from customerB where id = ?
    union all 
select 
    Num as Dealer,
    owner as Name
from customerC where id = ?`

I have a input text box in the report itself and a refresh button which reload the report.
also my report have parameter called 'CUST_ID' which i bound in the dataset as param_1,param_2 and param_3 to replace with '?' mark while executing.

if i enter the parameter on parameter popup screen report works fine , but i need to enter the id in the text box and once i press the refresh link reload report accordingly.

How can i add the input text value ( i know i can get it from a script ) and set it to the report parameter 'CUST_ID' ?

Highly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'CUST_ID' parameter to the end of your URL that you use when refreshing the report?  It would look something like this;    http://reports.com/run?__report=YourReport.rptdesign&CUST_ID=Value

Comment: Thank you @JamesJenkins for the comments. here the thing is i do not have any control in the request URL. in the 'refresh' link i just use link to attribute and gave the same report. I see i can get the query text through 'this.queryText' on datasource 'beforeOpen' method. still am not sure what i am doing is correct coz am new to BIRT. Thank you again for your turn back. if you have anything please let me know.

Comment: I have not done it, but I have read about in a couple posts at http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/ I think what you want to do is rework your refresh button, so that you control the url and are able to create it at report run time with values entered by the user as the parameters.  I have a couple reports that run as html by default, and contain a link to run as xls, I have been considering adding the carry over parameter feature to them but other priorities...  If you can put together a 'how to' answer I would like to read it.

Comment: Thanks James. In my case the thing is i am building this report on top of a custom application and that application handles requests , responses internally. so i do not have any control over it except some of the defined parameters that i can use.  :(

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by using scripts in BIRT. below i listed the steps i follow.

1.add a script that will initiate the request parameters on page load.
   report url i was able to access by using `var link=this;` inside a normal javascript   function.

2.Append my parameter to the end of the request as mentioned by james above. thanks james.

3.replace the newly created url `link.href=url;`  This will refresh the report with the value i entered in the input box.

4.in data set i modified my query as `'Select name from customerA'` without any where clause.

5.dataset `beforeOpen` script i added these line and records are filterd accordingly.

```
this.queryText += "where id ="+reportContext.getParameterValue("cust_id");
reportContext.setParameterValue("debug", this.queryText);
```